# Update in jsp from Servlet not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I have two servlets BookSaleAuction and MemberServlet and some jsp files for insert and update as index.jsp and MemberDetailUpdate.jsp and
in MemberDetailUpdate.jsp

```
<form method= "post" action="/booksaleauction">
  UserName : <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=editname%>">
  Address : <input type="text" name="address" value="<%=address%>">
  Contact : <input type="tel" name="contactNo" value="<%=contact%>">
  Email : <input type="email" name="email" value="<%=editemail%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=editID%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="formAction" value="update">

  <input type="submit" name="Update">
</form>
```

and  in BookSaleAuctionServlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String form = request.getParameter("formAction");
    System.out.print(form);
}
```

and in MemberServlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.print("into member servlet ");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");
        String contact = request.getParameter("contactNo");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class not found " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("JDBC Class found");
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement st = null;

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/logins", "root", "");
            String sql = "UPDATE members SET username=?, email=?, contact=?, address=? WHERE id=?";
           // ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Users SET password=?, fullname=?, email=? WHERE id=id");
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, name);
            statement.setString(2, email);
            statement.setString(3, contact);
            statement.setString(4, address);


            int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsUpdated > 0) {
                System.out.println("An existing user was updated successfully!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL exception occured" + e);
        }
        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("MemberDetail.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SQL exception occured" + e);
        }
```

in both servlet whenever there is update done in jsp there is no any further action being done . It is not working for the form even if i change action and method to run from another servlet `BookSaleAuction` Plz help i dont know what is the mistake i have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this links,

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/

I have done my servlet example,
https://github.com/oguzpamuk/Dynamic-Web-Project-Example

Comment: thanks but i have already done insert in database but it is not working for update. I just wanted to know why it is not working and make it work.